# how to use "visualstate" to modify child usercontrol's status in xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, windows-10-mobile

I'm doing something windows 10 UWP app development,and I got a problem,Thanks all for help,blew is my code:

In MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid  Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Pivot Style="{StaticResource fuckpivot}" SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged">
        <PivotItem>
            <PivotItem.Header>
                <local:test Label="item 3" Glyph="&#xE723;" />
            </PivotItem.Header>
            <Rectangle 
                      x:Name="MyAnimatedRectangle"
                      Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Blue" />
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem>
            <PivotItem.Header>
                <local:test Label="item 2" Glyph="&#xE723;" HighLight="Transparent"/>
            </PivotItem.Header>
            <!--<Rectangle x:Name="MyTest" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="red"/>-->
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>

</Grid>
```

and my "testControl":

```
   <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
        <FontIcon
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Margin="0,12,0,0"
                        Glyph="{Binding Glyph}"
                        FontSize="16" />
        <TextBlock
                        FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                        Text="{Binding Label}"
                        Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"
                        LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"
                        LineHeight="14"
                        MaxLines="2"
                        IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="False"
                        TextAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Margin="2,5,2,7" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" BorderBrush="Red"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

So, my question is :how to change the highlight color in the child UserControl named"test"?(when pivot change to the current Index, how to write the visual state?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested it on WP8.1 RunTime, but in this case I believe that it hadn't changed that much. The sample below is using *VisualStateManager* to change the `Label.Foreground` to *Green*. Code is mostly in XAML and goes like this:

MainPage:

```xml
<Grid  Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Pivot SelectionChanged="Pivot_SelectionChanged">
        <PivotItem>
            <PivotItem.Header>
                <local:testControl Label="item 3" Glyph="&#xE723;" />
            </PivotItem.Header>
            <Rectangle 
                  x:Name="MyAnimatedRectangle"
                  Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Blue" />
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem>
            <PivotItem.Header>
                <local:testControl Label="item 2" Glyph="&#xE723;"/>
            </PivotItem.Header>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

testControl:

```xml
<Grid>        
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="MyLabel">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Green"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
        <FontIcon   HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,12,0,0" Glyph="{Binding Glyph}" FontSize="16" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="MyLabel" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Text="{Binding Label}" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" LineHeight="14"
                   TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,5,2,7" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" BorderBrush="Red"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

To make this work you will only have to change *VisualStates* when pivot selection changes - this goes in MainPage's code behind:

```cs
private void Pivot_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
        VisualStateManager.GoToState((e.RemovedItems.First() as PivotItem).Header as testControl, "Unselected", true);
    if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
        VisualStateManager.GoToState((e.AddedItems.First() as PivotItem).Header as testControl, "Selected", true);
}
```

You should also find more help [at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstate.Aspx) and probably more at some blogs and articles.

Comment: you just move the usercontrol's code outside the control??

Comment: does custom control has "selected "and "unselected" state?

Comment: @Daniel.Woo You don't move usercontrol's code outside the control, just inform the visualstatemanager to change the visual state of the control. It can be also done different ways, also defining everything in xaml.

Comment: Sorry ,I mean "my custom control has no VisualStates like selected, unselected," but "my custom control" 's  parent control is a "pivot control" Which has such states like "selected ,unselected"

Comment: @Daniel.Woo No problem. The control somehow has to know when to change the state.